# Detect the unknown character in string

Tags: c#

I am having trouble combating cheaters who join the game (MW3) with a name like this:[image: this].

It appears to be an unknown character symbol. I am trying to build a function that detects whether a passed string contains said symbol, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

These are not unknown symbols, they are known for any other language, if you want to use only English characters, then you can use regular expression to validate string, if your string is in set of (0-9,a-z,A-z) then you can call it as valid, you can add English special characters in this set.

Answer (score -1):

The unknown character in your string in the question is a non-ASCII character (it is a UniCode character). With the help of the below method you can detect whether the string contains any non-ASCII characters:

```
public bool ContainsNonAsciiCharacter(string input)
{
    const int MaxAnsiCode = 127;

    return input.Any(c => c > MaxAnsiCode);
}
```